# How to create the patch file for newly added files using source tree

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I want to create the patch file for newly added files in Git using source tree. I've created the same using **create patch** option in Actions menu. But the patch is showing empty and unable to find the newly added file information in the patch.

How do I create the patch for newly added files in the source tree?

Comment: Is the file empty?

Comment: By newly added, do you mean added to the index or newly committed?

Comment: @ckruczek yes it is empty..
@ LightBender newly added to my working repository.

Comment: You can't make a patch from a empty file. There is no difference on file level.

Comment: @ckruczek sorry,  file is not empty.. created patch file is empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First **stage** the newly added files and then create a patch for those staged files. It will work.